# NavigationService.GoBack() skips a page

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, navigation, navigationservice

I'm using `NavigationService.GoBack()` to close a page once the user finished his input.

The backstack is printing fine, so I'm sure that all the pages are stored correctly, but calling `GoBack()` makes it skip a page and I don't know why.

Here's my backstack before calling `GoBack()`

> ```
> -----BACKSTACK-----
> found /Model;component/TestPage.xaml
> found /MainPage.xaml
> ```

I expect it to navigate to `TestPage.xaml`, so I'm checking using this line:

```
Debug.WriteLine("Navigating to " + NavigationService.BackStack.First().Source);
```

and here's its output:

> Navigating to /Model;component/TestPage.xaml

As I already said, it skips a page so it prints correctly but it navigates to `MainPage.xaml`.

I've tried with this code instead of `GoBack()`

```
NavigationService.Navigate(NavigationService.BackStack.First().Source);
```

and it seems to work because it navigates to the right page, but it suddenly goes forward, navigating to the page which called that line.

Please keep in mind that `TestPage.xaml`, and the page from which I'm navigating, are instances of `BasePage` which extends `PhoneApplicationPage`.

Does anyone have a clue?

---

EDIT: Seems like that removing the class that extended `PhoneApplicationPage` made everything work again.
Quite weird anyways, but at least it works!

Comment: Has Navigation to TestPage.xaml completed? It can be in the backstack but not yet navigated to yet, which might be causing you issues. Try with System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => GoBack());

Comment: It has. Actually, the route is the following: `MainPage -> TestPage -> Settings` and TestPage is shown and active, because I click a button on `TestPage` to move to `Settings`. But calling `NavigationService.GoBack()` while in the `Settings` page, takes me back to `MainPage`. I've got two types of `Settings`, one extends `PhoneApplicationPage` and the the other is just a `PhoneApplicationPage`. The second one takes me back to `TestPage`, the first goes back to `MainPage`